e.preventDefault doesnt work in onChange event, React
I'm trying to change the type of input from number to text, but I want user can type there only numbers, dot or comma. I wrote the onChange handler that checked if input contains only allowed symbols and delete all that not. locally it works well, but in the project still possible type in input letters and other symbols. Seems that return and e.preventDefault just don't work there.
The project code that doesn't work:
const onChangeMin = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    const node = e.target as HTMLInputElement;

    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    const parent = node.closest('.aside-filters')!.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const element = node.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    setShowButton(true);
    setTopButton(element - parent);

    timeOut = setTimeout(() => {
      setShowButton(false);
    }, 7000);

    if (node.value.match(/[^0-9.,]/g)) {
      return;
    } else {
      setMinValue(node.value.replace(',', '.'));
    }
  };

local code that works well:
const onChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if (e.target.value.match(/[^0-9.,]/g)) {
            e.preventDefault()
        } else {
            setValue(e.target.value.replace(',', '.'));
        }
    }

Is the problem in async timeout? How can I fix this?

see this TL;DR change event is not cancellable

hm, so why locally it works?

Good point - why DOES it work locally - what is the point of doing preventDefault in your code? i.e. what happens locally when you do that compared to not locally

Oh, wait ... locally code is completely different to code that doesn't work ... you are comparing apples with lemons and expect to glean some insight into some issue

[Btw, your example is not minimal as we don't care about parent, element or showButton and topPosition.]
return here will not do anything and just stop running the rest of the function, which here does nothing more. Your code would be equivalent to:
if (!node.value.match(/[^0-9.,]/g)) {
  setMinValue(node.value.replace(',', '.'));
}

What you can do if you want to prevent the user to type different characters is probably something close to:
node.value = node.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '');
setMinValue(node.value.replace(',', '.'));

Or if you want to let them type the other characters but strip them for your action, just:
setMinValue(node.value.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '').replace(',', '.'));


oh, thank u for answer, but it still doesn't work...
it replaces the comma for a dot but keep letters..

i suppose the problem in the context but dont know where..
